# Hide DIV on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to hide a DIV element when the page loads and after the Purchase now buton is clicked then the DIV element loads. Right now it shows when the page loads and when clicked it hides, even when i switch the "block" and "none" around in the function it still does not work? Can anyone please help me to hide it on load?

Thanks

Show & Hide Script:

```
  function showhide()
     {
     var div = document.getElementById("newpost");
    if (div.style.display !== "none") {
        div.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = "block";
    }
     }
```

DIV element:

```
<div id="newpost" class="hidden">

    Enter Your First Name:</td> <input type="text"  size="10">
    <br>
    Enter Your Surname: <input type="text"  size="10">
    <br>
    Enter Your Address: <input type="text"  size="10">
    <br>
    Enter Your E-mail: <input type="text"  size="10">
    <br>

    <input type="button" value="Submit Purchase" id="B1" onClick="final()">
</table>
            </div>
```

Called By:

```
        Basket: <input type="text" id="Total"  disabled="disabled" > <input type="button" value= "Purchase Now" onclick ="showhide()">  <input type="button" value= "Clear Basket" onclick ="showhide()">
```

Comment: Use CSS: `#newpost { display: none; }`

Comment: What calls `showhide`?

Comment: I'm not sure if the Purchase Now button you mention in your post is the same as the Submit Purchase button in your code, but if it is, hiding the div when the page loads will also hide the button. If that's the case, you'd need to take the input tag out of the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a CSS to hide it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>...</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #newpost {
                display: none;
            }
        <style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- ...... -->
    </body>
</html>
```

That means your DIV will be hidden by default (according to style rules) and your function will show it when called.

The rest of your code should do fine (remember to block clicking the "Purchase now" button when clicked so it won't be pressed again and, thus, your DIV will hide again).

Comment: +1 for not advising a redundant call to jQuery on page load.  Other answers were way to overkill for the usecase.